# NavBar To be be on the top horizontal right hand side

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling in setting my Navbar horizontally on the right hand side.

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #02082c;
  color: #f9f9f9;
}

.container {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.brand {}

.logo {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar .nav-list {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.navbar .nav-item {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="brand">
      <h1><a href="#" class="logo">GOLD</a></h1>
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li class="nav-list"><a href="#" class="nav-item">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-list"><a href="#" class="nav-item">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="nav-list"><a href="#" class="nav-item">Services</a></li>
      <li class="nav-list"><a href="#" class="nav-item">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set *flex* to `#header`, but all the aligned elements are in your `.container`. It is enough to transfer or add flex-properties to the `.container`.

```css
* {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: #f9f9f9;
  background-color: #02082c;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 85%;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.navbar .nav-item {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="brand">
      <h1><a href="#" class="logo">GOLD</a></h1>
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li class="nav-list"><a href="#" class="nav-item">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-list"><a href="#" class="nav-item">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="nav-list"><a href="#" class="nav-item">Services</a></li>
      <li class="nav-list"><a href="#" class="nav-item">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```